# Багнутое site description выдает описание старого сайта, как исправить? в коде вообще нету этого слова

Tags: html

[image: R]

```
 <title>ТОО КОМПАНИЯ ФАКТУМ</title>

    <meta name="description" content="ТОО КОМПАНИЯ ФАКТУМ">
  <meta property="og:description" content="ТОО КОМПАНИЯ ФАКТУМ">
  <meta property="og:title" content="ТОО КОМПАНИЯ ФАКТУМ">
```

вроде бы прописал все но все равно старый description вылетает в коде страницы нигде не прописано слово bi innovations кто знает что еще надо изменить?

Comment: закешировалось-

Comment: в телеге думал ссылку отправить а там вылазит старая в description

Comment: Закешировалось-